In SwiftUI, is it possible to create Excel files, populate them, and store them in Apple's Files App?
I'm trying to find a way to natively create an excel file using SwiftUI. However, I have learned that it is notas simple of a task to perform
Currently, I am facing challenges finding a package or tool that effectively creates and stores Excel files. Despite trying various approaches, including using UIDocumentPickerViewController for directory selection and SwiftXLSX for file creation, the process is proving difficult, and the generated files aren’t appearing in the expected location within the Files app.
Does anyone know of any package that would reliably and effectively create excel files and store them in the Files app?

try native TabularData framework

There are some libraries available for this purpose like libxlsxwriter here is tutorial for how to implement this in swift here is anothor one xlsxwriter you can check both of them and try which ever fits your pupose batter.

Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it., from the Help Center
